# Select2: filter static data with my own function

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select2 with static data.
I need to get results based on my own function, not the default one.
Select2 searches inside the 'text'. I want to search inside 'text' and 'synonymous'.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using 'matcher' method will solve this issue:

```
$("#select").select2({
    matcher: function(term, obj){
        this_text = obj.text;
        synonymous = obj.synonymous;
        term = term.term;

        if(this_text.indexOf(term) > -1 || synonymous.indexOf(term) > -1){
                return obj;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
    }
});
```